# CSS <td> tag affecting entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, servicenow

I'm creating a CMS page within ServiceNow and have created a table in Jelly script:

```
<g:evaluate var="jvar_job_details">
var selection = new GlideRecord('u_selection');  
selection.addQuery('u_selection_user.u_candidate_name', gs.getUserID());
selection.query();
var title_list = "<table>";
    title_list += "<tr> <th>" + 'Job Title' + "</th> <th>" + 'Location' + "</th> <th>" + 'Position Number' + "</th> <th>" + 'Certification Number' + "</th> <th>" + 'Grade' + "</th> <th>" + 'Series' + "</th> </tr>";
while(selection.next()) {
    title_list += 
    "<tr> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_job_title.getHTMLValue() +  "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_job_location.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_position_number.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_certification_number.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_grade.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_series.getHTMLValue() + "</td> </tr>" ;
    }
    title_list += "</table>";
</g:evaluate>
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant way to do it, but the table indeed shows up.  I, then, used CSS to style the table:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
}

th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Pretty simple stuff.  However, the  padding:0.5rem; is giving me fits because it is affecting the entire page, despite this being the table in the entire page. When that part of the code is in, the entire page seems to get padded.  I added a background-color: red to the td element in order to troubleshoot and narrow it the issue down and this is where I'm stuck.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: provide an fiddle can u?

Comment: Is the base of the page a table?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have created more tables in your page.

Give an Id to the created table. I mean change this

`var title_list = "<table>";`

to

`var title_list = "<table id='myTable'>";`

And Change your css like

```
#myTable th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CMS tool that most-likely is already adding a lot of mark-up for you I'd suggest to add a class to that table you're creating and style the table using that css class rather than style all tables and cells

Adding a class to the table...

```
var title_list = "<table class='myClass'>";
```

and then style the rest...

```
table.myClass{}

table.myClass th, table.myClass td{}
```

Comment: Leo, thanks!  by giving the table a class, it fixed the styling issue, but now the table doesn't generate.  any thoughts?